# IF..ELSE Logic in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I need to pull data from a table column based on an input parameter.

If the input parameter is `'Y'` I need to pull only `'Y'` values from the table column, if it is `'N'`, I need to pull all values irrespective of `'Y'` or `'N'` or `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this can be expressed as an if...else condition, it can also be expressed as a simple `OR`:

```
SELECT <ColumnsList> 
FROM <TableName>
WHERE <Column> = @Param
OR @Param = 'N'
```

Please note that this approach doesn't prevent you to get all the data from the table where `<Column>` contains `'P'`, for example - because the value of `@Param` can be anything.
If you want only `'Y'` and `'N'`, you should add another condition:

```
SELECT <ColumnsList> 
FROM <TableName>
WHERE (
    <Column> = @Param
    AND @Param = 'Y'
)
OR @Param = 'N'
```

With this query, any value of `@Param` other than `'Y'` or `'N'` will not return anything from the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your stored procedure where clause as shown below.

```
Create Procedure <YourProcedureName>
@Filter Varchar(20)
as
Begin
  Select <colName1>
  , <ColName2>
  , <ColName..N>
  From <YourTableName>
  where @filter = 'N' OR <YourColName> = @filter
END
```

You need to replace the actual procedure name you want and also the table and the column name as in the table.

Comment: `@filter <> 'N' AND` is redundant.

Comment: You can edit it yourself, you don't need me to do it... just remove the redundant part.

Comment: Yes, it is (though the parenthesis are also redundant now).